# Pronouns referring to parts of the same sentence other than the subject

Tags: pronouns, reflexive

Many European languages have specific pronouns for the case that the subject and an object are identical, e. g.

|  | Reflexive | Non-reflexive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Engl. | "Peter sees *himself* (in the mirror)" | "Peter sees him (somebody else)" |
| Dan. | "Peter ser *sig*" | "Peter ser ham" |
| Pol. | "Peter widzi *siebie*" | "Peter widzi *go*" |

In some languages other than English this is extended to possessive pronouns referring to the subject, e. g.

|  | Reflexive | Non-reflexive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Engl. | "The mother gives the daughter her book (the mother's)" | "The mother gives the daughter her book (somebody else's)" |
| Dan. | "Moderen giver datteren *sin* bog" | "Moderen giver datteren *hendes* bog" |
| Pol. | "Matka daje córce *swoją* książkę" | "Matka daje córce *jej* książkę" |

In the first column, it is clear whose book we are talking about but the examples on the right are ambiguous. Are there languages that have specific pronouns (personal or possesive) to refer to other parts of a sentence (indirect or direct object) or the preceding one, e. g. picking up the previous subject and use it as the new object?

I have already found out about obviative pronouns. They seem, however, to focus on the semantic role of a word or the implied relationship between the words. I am only interested in languages that assign pronouns based on the syntactic role of a noun phrase.

Comment: In the second table, I note that we can say "her own book", in which case it means either the mother's or the daughter's, but not a third party's... If their grammatical genders were different, it would be unambiguous!

Comment: Navajo has 4 persons, the 4th person is used for the one(s) outside of discourse, and there's one more indefinite person for ‘somebody’. So, I guess, in the 2nd column of the 2nd chart, the 3rd p. possessive prefix will mean ‘her (mother's) book’, the 4th p. will mean ‘‘her (daughter's) book’, and the indefinite person possessive will mean ‘someone else's book’.

Comment: You say words referring to "parts of the same sentence other than the subject". However, in English, for example, a reflexive pronoun might easily refer to an Object: "I gave Brenda a picture of herself". From the perspective of someone only intimately familiar with the syntax of English, the key point is that in the examples you give in the second table, the pronoun is a Determiner within the noun phrase. In English Determiners are never reflexive.

Comment: (continued) and NPs that co-refer with them are not reflexive unless they occur within the same NP, regardless of whether they are a Subject or Object, etc.

Comment: @Araucaria. Determiners  in English can in fact be reflexive (and must be at times) if "own" is added, e.g. "John is his boss" vs. "John is his own boss". In the second sentence, "his own" is determinative and necessarily corefers with "John", making it reflexive in the relevant sense.

Comment: @TimOsborne Yes, I'm aware of *own*, of course ;)  But not really a reflexive in the relevant sense here: a) *his* and *own* are separate words and you can insert intervening material between the two b) *his* is a  pronoun and *own* an adjective, neither a reflexive c) they appear within two different phrases within the NP, *his* in the Determiner  and *own* in the nominal Head. Given that *own* does not appear within the Determiner, it can't be part of a  reflexive Determiner (i.e. a. reflexive word/item in Determiner function). [Although it semantically it might do a similar job]

Comment: @TimOsborne I do like the interesting own boss example, but notice that what seems to be the driving factor there is that *his* and *boss* also co-refer within the same NP and where *his* has a semantic role in relation to the meaning of *boss*. (It seems to me)

Comment: Note that the reciprocal pronouns _each other_ and  _one another_ can also occur carved up: _They know each other; They know one another; Each (one) knows the other (one)_. And they can be used together in interesting ways: _Each man thinks the other is smarter than he is; Each man thinks the other is smarter than himself._  Accounting for the reflexive in the last subordinate clause is troublesome.

Comment: @Araucaria. You write that other words can appear between the possessive and _own_. Would you provide an example, please. I am aware that _very_ can do this, e.g. _his very own house_, but that is because _very_ modifies _own_ directly. Other examples seems dubious, e.g. ??_his two own houses_ vs. _his own two houses_.

Comment: @TimOsborne I was thinking about *very* in particular, but now you present it *his two own houses* seems grammatical, if marked, to me. For example "He didn't have nearly as much trouble with the houses he looked after as he had with his two own houses". *Very* can modify *own*, of course, precisely because *own* is an adjective (which happens to be in a separate phrase from *his*).

Comment: @jlawler That comparative in itself is mind boggling when you start to think about it, even without the reflexive.

Comment: @TimOsborne Just another thought, which do you feel is reflexive in *He was his own boss*? For me, is seems to be the case that *own boss* constitutes an analytic reflexive (bound by *his*), not that *his own* is the reflexive. What do you think?

Comment: @Araucaria. I view _his own_ as a constituent that can take a coargument antecedent. Thus in the example, _John_ and _his own_ are coarguments, which means _his own_  functions as a reflexive. A similar situation obtains in sentences like _John is and admirer of him_ vs. _John is an admirer of himself_, where we see that _John_ and _him/himself_ should be viewed as coarguments due to the complementarity in distribution of the relevant pronoun forms (reflexive vs. simple pronoun).

Comment: @Araucaria. My recent research efforts are focusing on binding theory. One thing I have not (yet) encountered anywhere in the literature, though, concerns the actual structural analysis of _own_. You apparently view it as an attributive adjective. I am not sure about the analysis, though. If you know of any literature that addresses the status and position of _own_ inside the nominal group, please share that source with me.

Comment: @TimOsborne They do not discuss why, but Huddleston & Pullum 2002 give *own* as an adjective p. 482-3 in their analysis. Here's some thoughts for you, though: I don't think that *own* is ever required unless the genitive Determiner  plays a semantic role in relation to the Head noun. Consider the following where we assume that *Bob* and *his* co-refer in both cases: *Bob had become his teacher* versus *Bob had become his own teacher.* The second implies that Bob was now teaching himself. The same applies to the *boss* example. Note that a genitive Determiner often requires ...

Comment: @TimOsborne other NPs contained within its NP to be reflexive "Bob's picture of himself", for example. My intuition leads me to think that at least part of any binding effect in your example must relate to the genitive Determiner playing a semantic role in relation to the Head noun.

Comment: @Araucaria. Thanks to pointing to H&P 2002, which I have taken a look at. Their analysis of _own_ as an attributive adjective faces difficulties in my view. One problem is that _own_ would be unlike other attributive adjectives in that it cannot occur without the pronoun, e.g. _his own things_ vs. _*own things_ vs. _old things_, _big things_, etc.  It seems to behave more like the complex determinative _a few_, e.g. _a few things_ vs. _*a few thing_, where we see that _a few_ is necessarily plural despite the presence of singular _a_.

Comment: @Araucaria. I agree that the possessive determiner can receive a semantic role from the predicative noun. The analysis I prefer builds centrally on this possibility. Thus in _John is his own boss_, the matrix predicate is _is boss_ such that _John_ and _his own_ become coarguments. Similarly in your sentence _Bob had become his own teacher_. The predicate is _had become teacher_ such that _Bob_ and _his own_ are coarguments. Note that the coreferential reading in _Bob had become his teacher_ seems unlikely to me, which is predicted if, as I claim, the matrix predicate is _had become teacher_.

Comment: @TimOsborne You might want to take a look at 2.1.1 of [Payne 2011](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/genitive-coordinations-with-personal-pronouns1/93AF2F9446B6C327FDDBEB4E22883F3D) and the references he discusses in footnote 8.

Comment: "*One problem is that own would be unlike other attributive adjectives in that it cannot occur without the pronoun, e.g. his own things vs. *own things vs. old things, big things, etc*" <-- I get this train of thought. However, that's what we'd expect if *own* forms a reflexive nominal with the head noun. If it's reflexive because it co-refers with the genitive Determiner, then it won't occur without a genitive determiner! [Yes, argument was the word I was reaching for when I said 'semantic role']

Comment: @TimOsborne I think one natural interpretation of  *Bob had become his teacher* is that Bob had adopted the customs/mannerisms/dress sense/attitudes/lifestyle of his  erstwhile teacher. A bit like how we talk about people becoming their parents etc. But that interpretations only available if *his* is not an argument of *teacher.* So it can't mean *Bob became the person who teaches Bob.* (I think.) However, *Bob* and *his* still co-refer there. Although neither do straightforwardly with *teacher.* [PS forgot to ping you in comment further above]

Comment: @TimOsborne  Should the feeling take you, shall we [continue this discussion in chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139923/discussion-between-araucaria-him-and-tim-osborne). The "we don't like you chatting under here"-type message is popping up.